# Поиск файлов в папке по шаблону из файла

Tags: bash, debian, поиск

Есть папка с файлами:

```
0-{guid}.txt
1-{guid}.txt
..
N-{guid}.txt
```

`{guid}` - случайный цифро-буквенный набор длиной 16 символов.

Есть текстовый файл в котором построчно записи:

```
5
34
100
..
K
```

Задача сделать выборку из папки с `.txt` файлами под нужными номерами.
Т.е. в данном случае должны, например в файл записаться ( `>> test.log` ):

```
/path/to/file/5-{guid}.txt
/path/to/file/34-{guid}.txt
...
```

Хотел с помощью `find`, но он не вытаскивает шаблон из файла.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Файл `test.sh`:

```
#!/bin/bash

while read -r line
do
    file=($(find /path/to/file -name "$line-*"))
    echo $file
done < "123.txt"
```

`123.txt` - файл с числами.

`/path/to/file` - каталог с файлами.

Запуск: `./test.sh > test.log`

*PS* рассмотрен самый простой вариант: файлы в каталоге существуют и в одном экземпляре. Т.е. любое число из файла 123.txt будет однозначно определять только один существующий файл из каталога `/path/to/file`.

Comment: Спасибо, про цикл я и не подумал.

Comment: Дополнение, чтоб прочитать все строки файла: `while read line || [ -n "$line" ]; do`

Answer (score 1):

Все примерны относительно текущей позиции ./

Если нужно залогировать вывод используйте `>>` или `tee`

В одну строчку и ключем для отображения только файлов

```
~$ xargs -I% find ./ -type f -name "%-*" < 123.txt
```

Вариант быстрей (используя Rust fd):

```
~$ xargs -I{} fd -t f "{}-.{16}" ./ < 123.txt
```

Вариант еще быстрей и в любом месте (может не подойти т.к. ищет по всем каталогом.):

```
~$ xargs -I{} locate --regex "{}-.*" < 123.txt
```

**Проверка**

Создадим 100 файлов по шаблону в вопросе:

```
~$ touch {1..100}-$(strings /dev/urandom | head -n100 | egrep -o '[a-zA-Z1-9]+' | sed -e ':a;N;$!ba;s/\n//g' -e 's/ //g' -e 's/\t//g' | fold -c16 | egrep -om1 '.{16}').txt
```

Случайным образом генерируем список в выборке от 1 до 100 и возьмем первые 10:

```
 ~$ seq 100 | sort -R | head | tee 123.txt
90
16
13
47
59
87
50
37
94
28
```

Первый пример:

```
~$ time xargs -I% find ./ -type f -name "%-*" < 123.txt
./90-F1NbaiYrPSzhgTKD.txt
./16-QicUkZaseC5zr7p8.txt
./13-Q1dx492pLFGAiTTs.txt
./47-SAprVh4BYClsvhql.txt
./59-P74upGNO84eFfxz9.txt
./87-ZWCwqfn9bauguZAx.txt
./50-jhPN1RdGpL9cmnzL.txt
./37-qWX7jnnMUBrFnKtk.txt
./94-qnlwAZpQhmPsTOWR.txt
./28-snggGXHkqJBmW8il.txt
real    0m0.137s
user    0m0.054s
sys     0m0.082s
```

Второй пример:

```
~$ time xargs -I{} fd -t f "{}-.{16}" ./ < 123.txt
90-F1NbaiYrPSzhgTKD.txt
16-QicUkZaseC5zr7p8.txt
13-Q1dx492pLFGAiTTs.txt
47-SAprVh4BYClsvhql.txt
59-P74upGNO84eFfxz9.txt
87-ZWCwqfn9bauguZAx.txt
50-jhPN1RdGpL9cmnzL.txt
37-qWX7jnnMUBrFnKtk.txt
94-qnlwAZpQhmPsTOWR.txt
28-snggGXHkqJBmW8il.txt
real    0m0.121s
user    0m0.372s
sys     0m0.142s
```

Пример три, немного переделенный, и оказался не таким быстрым как предполагал. По какой то причине `locate` не воспринимает regex шаблон из `xargs`. Потенциальное преимущество - это сканирование базы данных а не "сырой" поиск по фс.

```
~$ time { locate .txt > locate.log; xargs -I{} egrep -o "{}-.{16}" locate.log < 123.txt; }
90-F1NbaiYrPSzhgTKD
16-QicUkZaseC5zr7p8
16-300.fc27.x86_64/
13-Q1dx492pLFGAiTTs
47-SAprVh4BYClsvhql
59-P74upGNO84eFfxz9
87-ZWCwqfn9bauguZAx
50-jhPN1RdGpL9cmnzL
37-qWX7jnnMUBrFnKtk
94-qnlwAZpQhmPsTOWR
28-snggGXHkqJBmW8il
real    0m0.409s
user    0m0.372s
sys     0m0.036s
```

**Сылки**

- https://github.com/sharkdp/fd
- https://www.gnu.org/software/findutils/
- https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?locate(1)

Comment: Короче, ни один из вариантов не работает. Во втором случае пишет, что нет файла: `xargs: fd: No such file or directory`

Comment: @imsysmem `fd` это альтернатива `find` на Rust (смотрите ссылки в ответе). Обновил с примерами.